# Change Navbar Logo Font

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, frontend

Is there a way to change the font of the logo, without having to the change the font of the entire page?

Or would I have to create an image using that font and insert into the Navbar?

I wanted to use a font from Google Fonts font for the logo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding font-family to inline style tag. In the below example if you change the font family then, only the font of logo changes to the specified font.

```
<a
   class="navbar-brand logo" 
   href="/" 
   style="font-family:verdana;font-size: 21px; color: #555">
   Sometext
</a>
```

Comment: Ahh. I'll have to mess with it a bit. You've definitely pushed me in the right direction. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Link HTML to an additional CSS class selector. Let's call it `changeFont` in this example.

```
 .changeFont
    {
       font-family: 'Some font name' !important;
    }
```

add class to anchor

```
<a class="changeFont">Logo Text</a>
```